Enabling WMS Item Alias Feature in NetSuite
I am working with NetSuite’s warehouse management system (WMS) and am attempting to enable the WMS item alias feature. Despite having already enabled both the basic and advanced WMS features in the system, I am unable to find the option to activate or configure WMS item alias.
How to enable this specific feature or any additional steps required?
Feature Location: Where exactly within NetSuite can I enable the WMS item alias functionality?
Prerequisites: Are there any other configurations or permissions that need to be set before this feature becomes available?
This is example of WMS item alias record

